# Jquery attr not working properly for Checkbox Required attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I try to toggle text box on checkbox's click event and it working fine. My Issue is that I also want to change checkbox's required attribute.

Here is my code which will remove required attribute but can not toggle it.

```
 $('#sender_name').change(function(event){

    if ($('#sender_name').attr('required', 'required'))
    {
        $('#sender_name').removeAttr('required', 'required');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#sender_name').attr('required', 'required');
    }

    $('.sender_name_text').toggle();
});
```

Using this code, checkbox's attribute will removed, but not appy again. check it in fiddle by inspect element.

Here Is [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/64r1o0oq/)

-- Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use `.attr` method as [getter](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1), like this

```
if ($('#sender_name').attr('required') == 'required') {
    $('#sender_name').removeAttr('required');
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/64r1o0oq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#sender_name').change(function(event){

if ($('#sender_name').attr('required')== 'required')
{
    $('#sender_name').removeAttr('required');
}
else
{
    ($('#sender_name').attr('required')== 'required')
}
```

here is the code `http://jsfiddle.net/64r1o0oq/`

```
$('.sender_name_text').toggle();
```

});

This should work...